# How to validate a column in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

In my user table i have a role column its values Teacher and Student. I want to insert data if user role teacher. Otherwise give a message "Only for teacher".
Here is my controller:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'title' => 'required|exists:users,role==[Teacher]',
                ]);
                if ($validator->fails()) {

                Flash::success('Only for Teacher');
                return redirect(route('works',['class_id'=>$class_id]));
                }else{
                $works = new assainments();
                $works -> title = $text;
                //$works -> file = $fileName;
                $works -> class_id = $class_id;
                $works -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $works -> save();
                Flash::success('Your works has been posted');
                return redirect(route('works',['class_id'=>$class_id]));
```

But it's not working. It's only Show the error message "Only for Teacher"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## laravel 5.2

The `exists` validator rules work given table , column and extra where conditions. See the more definition :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-exists

But you can solve this on another way by checking a if condition :

```
if( \Auth::user()->role == 'Student' )
{
    Flash::success('Only for Teacher');
    return redirect(route('works',['class_id'=>$class_id]));
}
```